# change caption color depending on image behind it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, caption

I'm working on a portfolio site that is a full browser size container where the image is swapped when moving the cursor from left to right. I achieved this with a jquery script called swinger.js.
I had some trouble adding captions to this but with some help from here last night I got it to work using the alt attribute. The problem is now that I want to have some of the captions in white and others in black (depending on the image behind it) and I would like the same to happen to the site title.
I added a class inside the img src tag that specifies which should be which. class=“swinger_img_white” for a white caption, class=“swinger_img_black” when it needs to be black
But I can't get it to work.

My coding experience goes be a week or two, I got this far by luck, help and dedication to trying code from other websites.
Any help would be much appreciated!

*note: with caption I just mean some text that goes with the image (explaining it) by whatever way is possible.
Does not have to be built like captions as used in webdesign, just has to work.

Here is what I have right now in a simplified version:

```js
$.fn.swinger = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $container = $(this);
        $container.css({
            "position": "relative"
        });
        var $images = $container.find("img");
        $images.css({
            
        });
        var $middleImage = $($images[Math.floor($images.length / 2)]);
        $middleImage.css({
            "z-index": "2",
            "position": "relative"
        });
        var columnsCount = $images.length;
        $images.each((i, img) => {
            var left = `${100 / columnsCount * i}%`;
            var width = `${100 / columnsCount}%`;
            var $column = $(`<span style="z-index:999;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:${left};width:${width}"></span>`);
            $(img).after($column);
            $column.hover(() => {
                $images.css({
                    "z-index": "1",
                    "position": "absolute"
                });
                $(img).css({
                    "z-index": "2",
                    "position": "relative"
                });
                // this was added last night for the captions
                $(".caption").text($(img).attr("alt"));

        
            });
        })
    });
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {

}

.left-holder {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 55px;
    width: 250px; }

div.swinger-container {
    text-align: center; /* ensures the image is always in the h-middle */
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 100vw;
height: calc(100vh);

}

div.swinger-container img {
    object-fit: cover;
-o-object-position: center center;
object-position: center center;
width: 100%;
height: 100% !important;
  }

  header {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: -2px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s; }
    header.header-about {
      color: white !important;
      background-color: white; }
    header h1, header h2, header .about {
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: 400;
      display: block;
      line-height: 1.2em;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0; }
    header h1 {
      text-align: left; }
    header a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      line-height: 1; }
    header .about {
      text-align: left;
      padding-bottom: 2px; }

      .left-holder{
          color:white
      }

        .caption {
            text-align: right;
            float: right;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title>website title</title>
    <script src="./jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <header>
        <div class="left-holder">
            <h1>my name</h1> 
            <h2>what I do</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">

        </div>
       
    </header>

    <div class="slides">
        <div class="swinger-container">
        
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447703693928-9cd89c8d3ac5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80" class=“swinger_img_white” alt="Caption 1"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502239608882-93b729c6af43?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class=“swinger_img_white” alt="Caption 2"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516557070061-c3d1653fa646?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class=“swinger_img_white” alt="Caption 3"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468657988500-aca2be09f4c6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class=“swinger_img_white” alt="Caption 4"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488554378835-f7acf46e6c98?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80" class=“swinger_img_white” alt="Caption 5"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491895200222-0fc4a4c35e18?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80" class=“swinger_img_black” alt="Caption 6"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517816743773-6e0fd518b4a6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" class=“swinger_img_black” alt="Caption 7"/>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548685913-fe6678babe8d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1923&q=80" class=“swinger_img_black” alt="Caption 8"/>
            
        </div> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(init);
        function init() 
        {
            $(".swinger-container").swinger();
        }
</script>

   <script src="swinger.js"></script>
    
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must use proper quotes `"` or `'` - not `“”` (6699) - https://jsfiddle.net/k8y0Lsrz/

Comment: thanks for the heads up! I had not noticed this mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be good if you keep some information about condition in a data attributes, like that:

```
<img src="https://..." data-color="white" alt="Caption 1"/>
<img src="https://..." data-color="black" alt="Caption 2"/>
```

Then you can change color of your caption with `.css` method which you will pass value from data-color attribute, like that:

```
$(".caption")
    .text($(img).attr("alt"))
    .css('color', $(img).data('color'));
```

Comment: awesome, this seems to work great, thank you !
is there a way to include the color of the header text?
"my name" "what I do"

Comment: you may use `.css('color', $(img).data('color'))` for header tag instead your caption like that `$('header').css('color', $(img).data('color'))`

Comment: works great! Do you think there is a way to make the jquery load instantly?
When I open the site now I have to move the cursor to make the title and caption appear.
Is there a way it is already there when I load the site? thank you so much

Comment: usually in real projects all static files is cached on a client side (browser cache), that allow them to load more quickly, also your images must load from the same folder as your html files i will be too much quicker than i will load from internet

Comment: ah I was not aware
when I test it out it just seems like I have to hover my cursor to make the swinger.js happen in order for the header and caption to appear, maybe the code hides it to start?